# Using python, trying to find the color range around the brightest point of an image by cropping out the brightest point

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a program that detects and then circles the brightest part of an image. I need to be able to get the range of color values within the circled area, and I'm thinking of doing that by cropping out the circled area and then getting the pixel color values for everything in the cropped image.

But I am not sure how to crop out part of the image based on where the brightest point is found.

Here is the code I have so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('opencv_frame_0.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('opencv_frame_1.png')
vis = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1)
cv2.imwrite('combined.png', vis)

# load the image and convert it to grayscale
#image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
image = cv2.imread('combined.png')
orig = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#perform a naive attempt to find the (x, y) coordinates of the area of the image with the largest intensity value
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)

# display the results of the naive attempt
cv2.imshow("Naive", image)
#apply a Gaussian blur to the image then find the brightest region
#gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (args["radius"], args["radius"]), 0)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (41, 41), 0)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
image = orig.copy()
#cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, args["radius"], (255, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, 41, (255, 0, 255), 2)
#display the results of our newly improved method
cv2.imshow("Robust", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is one of the ways I tried to crop out the bright area that didn't work

```
import numpy as np

import cv2

# load the image and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread('combined.png')
image1 = cv2.imread('combined.png', 0)
orig = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#perform a naive attempt to find the (x, y) coordinates of the area of the image with the largest intensity value
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)

# display the results of the naive attempt
#cv2.imshow("Naive", image)

#apply a Gaussian blur to the image then find the brightest region
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (41, 41), 0)
(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray)
image = orig.copy()
cv2.circle(image, maxLoc, 41, (255, 0, 255), 2)



#experimenting with cropping out the circle

height,width = image1.shape
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)

circle_img = cv2.circle(mask,(maxLoc,(255,255,255))

masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=circle_img)

_,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])

crop = masked_data[y:y+h,x:x+w]

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: We can't see your images.

Comment: The images shouldn't matter. It takes any two images, combines them, and then looks for the brightest point between those combined images. The images are of an LED light set at different brightnesses. The issue I'm having is cropping out the part of the image that I circle, or isolating that part of the image to get the color values within the circle.

Comment: _The images shouldn't matter._ They matter. They are part of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). People can't reproduce your code if you don't provide a complete script and its resources. Help people to help you.

Comment: There is a syntax error in line `circle_img = cv2.circle(mask,(maxLoc,(255,255,255))` with three opening and only two closing brackets. Also, please mind that if you want to draw to a one-channel image, you should only use a one-channel colour, i.e. just `255`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cut out the circled area to get the colour range within. You can apply the circular mask to [minMaxLoc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gab473bf2eb6d14ff97e89b355dac20707). Let's say you have the red channel of the image, then you can dirctly extract the red colour range:

```
mask = np.zeros((height, width), np.uint8)
circle_img = cv2.circle(mask, maxLoc, r, 255, cv2.FILLED)
minRed, maxRed, minLocRed, maxLocRed = cv.minMaxLoc(image_channel_red, mask=circle_img)
```